Variation of the derivative of field in 2d Sigma model
Consider 2d Sigma model, the Lagrangian is:
$$
\mathcal{L} = \frac{1}{2}\eta_{\mu\nu}\partial_{\alpha}X^{\mu}\partial_{\beta}X^{\nu}\sqrt{-h}h^{\alpha\beta}
$$
where $\eta=(-,+,+,\dots)$ is $D$-dimension Lorentzian metric, $X^\mu$ is D scalar fields, $h_{\alpha\beta}$ is an arbitrary 1+1-dimension metric and $h$ is its determinant.
We can derive the transformation for scalar field under 2d local Einstein transformation. $\sigma^{\alpha}\rightarrow\sigma^\alpha-\xi^{\alpha}(\sigma)=\sigma'^{\alpha}$.
which is
$$
\delta\phi := \phi'(\sigma)-\phi(\sigma)=\xi^{\gamma}\partial_{\gamma}X^{\mu}
$$
and also the variation for
$$
\delta h^{\alpha\beta} = -\partial_{\gamma}\xi^{\alpha}h^{\gamma\beta}-\partial_{\gamma}\xi^{\beta}h^{\gamma\alpha}+\xi^{\gamma}\partial_{\gamma}h^{\alpha\beta}
$$
and
$$
\delta(\sqrt{-h}) = -\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{-h}(-2\partial_{\alpha}\xi^{\alpha} + \xi^{\gamma}h_{\alpha\beta}\partial_{\gamma}h^{\alpha\beta})
$$
My question is: How to derive the $\delta(\partial_{\mu}\phi)$?
I've tried by using method below:
$$
\partial'_{\alpha}X'^{\mu} = \frac{\partial \sigma^{\beta}}{\partial \sigma'^{\alpha}}\partial_{\beta}X^{\mu}
$$
so
$$
\delta(\partial_{\alpha}X^{\mu}) = \frac{\partial \sigma^{\beta}}{\partial \sigma'^{\alpha}}\partial_{\beta}X^{\mu}+\partial_{\gamma}\left(\frac{\partial \sigma^{\beta}}{\partial \sigma'^{\alpha}}\partial_{\beta}X^{\mu}\right)\xi^{\gamma}-\partial_{\alpha}X^{\mu}
$$
But the Lagrangian should be invariant under 2d local Einstein transformation. Obviously this does not fit.
